# Easy way to forward javascript calls between parent window and iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, applet, cross-site

We initially had a web page that had HTML pull-down menus and an Applet.  Each of these pull-down menus triggers a javascript function which calls an applet function. The applet also invokes a javascript function to enable/disable the pull-down menus.

Problem is that the HTML pull-down menus are getting cut off by applet because most browsers ignore the z-index for applets. The only solution I found was to place the Applet into an iFrame.

Now all javascript calls to the applet that were getting triggered by the HTML pull-down are broken. Javascript invoked by Applet is now broken.

All javascript functions are stored in one big javascript file loaded in the parent window.

I been doing something like this but it will be a lot of work and will make maintenance to difficult:

```
var appletIFRAME= document.getElementById('appletIFRAME').contentWindow;
appletIFRAME.executeAction1= executeAction1; 
appletIFRAME.executeAction2= executeAction2;
...
...
```

This works ok but I believe I will also need to create wrapper javascript functions on both the parent window and the IFRAME web page. Also, our javascript functions are using jQuery to access HTML pull-down elements by ID's, which will also need to be refactored out.  This will be too much work.

So is there an easier way to call javascript between parent window and IFRAME? I want to avoid doing all this function mapping between parent window and iframe object. All javascript functions are stored in one javascript file loaded in parent window.

Just want to add that the HTML pull-down menus are located in parent window and Applet in the iFrame. This is the only way the pull-down menus will not get cut off by Applet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, there really isn't a way to do it that wouldn't require sweeping changes to your code, aside from not using iframes.

Comment: Check out [jquery postmessage](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/). You'll need to write a single message handler using it so that it calls the methods of the same name as called by the applet. Also see [the command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

Comment: tried "window.parent"? for example window.parent.callFunc()  from within the iframe?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Thinking about my case, there won't be too many changes, so I'll just go ahead and use the command pattern and manually mapping the calls between parent/iframe.